# Vaadin Button Click not registered

Tags: selenium, click, icons, vaadin

We have a Vaadin application with a heavily modified theme and have the problem occasionally that mouse-clicks are not properly acted upon. The border on the icon (png only, no text) is changed to indicate focus, but the action is not called. This happens for both users and our automated tests using Selenium/TestBench. We use Chrome/Chromium.

Update (2014-04-29):
The problem seems to have become less severe and has become less problematic for both our users and integration tests. We've run a special test case whereby we clicked a button continuously and checked whether it triggered a server request, and it failed only a few times in a couple of hundred clicks. We did however upgrade memory on our development server and integration testing desktop virtual machines as well which seem to have improved things by reducing memory swapping and response times.

Comment: Is the request fired to the server?

Comment: How can I check that, would I need to add debugging information to the server about click-events? The problem is it is happening at random, so it might be difficult to find the correct log entry?

Comment: Just a built-in browser debugger will be enough. If you use Chrome you can press F12 and then navigate to the "Network" tab. Then you can check if pressing the button in your app produces new POST request from the browser (new row will appear). This way you can determine if the problem comes from the client or from the server.